# can i have more than one end point in my wsdl?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, ejb, session-bean

HI, I have a webservice which is developed using ejb stateless sessionbeans - and it serves more than 10 clients , now we are planning to change the endpoint url to some other ... and for sometime i would like to keep the old and new both endpoints active ..once the clients are habituated to new one i would like to remove the old endpoint  -  so my question here is how can i have more than one end point in my wsdl?

how do I achieve it? responses appreciated .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of the `WSDL` there is a `<Service>` section. In here you can list each endpoint. This is from the [wikipedia entry on WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language):

```
<service name="RESTfulService" interface="tns:RESTfulInterface">
    <endpoint name="RESTfulServiceHttpEndpoint" 
            binding="tns:RESTfulInterfaceHttpBinding" 
            address="http://www.example.com/rest/"/>
    <endpoint name="RESTfulServiceSoapEndpoint" 
            binding="tns:RESTfulInterfaceSoapBinding" 
            address="http://www.example.com/soap/"/>
</service>
```